# how to sort a ruby collection based on data in another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a filtered list of companies:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Company id: 483, name: "Apple", description: "Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology...", social_website: "https://www.apple.com/">, #<Company id: 482, name: "Ceres Technology", description: "", social_website: "cerestech.co">]>
```

And a table called follows with has the amount of follower of each company:

```
query_chain.each do |company|
  total_followers_period = Follow.where('followable_type = ? AND followable_id = ? AND created_at > ?', "Company", company.id,1.week.ago).count
  total_followers_companies[company.id] =  total_followers_period
end
```

I need to order the list of companies based on the amount of rows it has into the follows table.

I tried returning an array and it works but i need to return the active record collection sorted by the amount of followers on the follows table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're going wrong here is that you're thinking in Ruby when you should be thinking in SQL.

In SQL you would group by company.id and order by the count of the number of rows in the joined table.

```ruby
Company.joins(:follows)
       .group(:id)
       .order(Follow.arel_table["*"].count.desc)
```

If you want to narrow that down to a count of the follows the latest week you can do it by adding a FILTER to the aggregate expression:

```ruby
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows, as: :followable

  def self.order_by_follows
    f = Follow.arel_table
    left_joins(:follows)
      .group(:id)
      .order(
        # COUNT(follows.*) FILTER WHERE(follows.created_at < ?)
        f[Arel.star].count.filter(f[:created_at].gt(1.week.ago.to_date)).desc
      )
  end 
end
```

[`FILTER` is available on Postgres and SQLite](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) and filters the rows going into the aggregate function. On other databases you would either do a custom join or a subquery to get the same result.

If you're using a version prior to Rails 7 you'll have to use a SQL string istead:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows, as: :followable

  def self.order_by_follows
    f = Follow.arel_table
    left_joins(:follows)
      .group(:id)
      .order(
        Arel.sql(
          "COUNT(follows.*) FILTER WHERE(follows.created_at < #{1.week.ago.to_date}) DESC"
        )
      )
  end 
end
```